# How can I get rmd160 digest of file in python (without subprocess)?

Tags: python

I know I can get the sha256 digest of a given file using `hashlib.sha256`, and could get the rmd160 digest using a `subprocess` call to `openssl rmd160 <myfile>`, but is there a python package I can `import` that provides a method to determine the rmd160 digest?

(rmd160 is a recommended checksum for use in a Macports Portfile [[1]](https://guide.macports.org/#development.creating-portfile).)

Comment: Afaik there is none, but you can look at a C-implementation and build your own module if you want to: ftp://ftp.esat.kuleuven.ac.be/cosic/bosselae/ripemd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not included in the standard library, but [pycrypto supports it](http://pythonhosted.org/pycrypto/Crypto.Hash.RIPEMD-module.html).

If you're using a unix system with access to a compiler and the required dependencies, you can simply `pip install pycrypto`. If you're using windows, there are [third party pre-built binaries](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/modules.shtml#pycrypto)

Answer (score 2):

You may use `hashlib.new(name)` to create hashers from the algorithm name.  My understanding of the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/hashlib.html) (both Python 2 and 3) is that in this case this is delegated to OpenSSL.  OpenSSL supports the names "rmd160" and "ripemd160".

I use

```
def rmd160(fname):
    BLOCKSIZE = 65536
    h = hashlib.new("rmd160")
    with open(fname, 'rb') as f:
        buf = f.read(BLOCKSIZE)
        while buf:
            h.update(buf)
            buf = f.read(BLOCKSIZE)
    return h.hexdigest()
```

Comment: This works, but beware when copy/pasting, there is a typo: `h = hashlib.new("rmd160")`